# Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $t=0$ for $\begin{cases}x = t^2 + 2t \\ y = 2t^3 - 6t\end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

A dot is moving on a grid  following this rule:
$$\begin{cases}x = t^2 + 2t \\ y = 2t^3 - 6t\end{cases}$$
I need to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $t =0$.

It seems like I should use implicit differentiation, but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: **HINT** $dx/dt = ?$, $dy/dt = ?$, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$

Comment: Thanks! Still I guess it's a good hint! :D Still kinda trying to figure it out, not really grasping this concept...

Comment: Compute the derivatives of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ with respect to $t$. Then use the fact that $$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$ in conjunction with my previous comment.

Comment: Why is dx = dx/dt?

Comment: @JesterJinx I found the answer is -3. You may please check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ x = t² + 2t, y = 2t³ - 6t $$

$$dx/dt= 2t + 2,$$
$$dy/dt= 6t²-6$$

You want $dy/dx$ for $t=0$. Just use algebra:

$$(6t²-6) /( 2t+2)$$ for t=0, then $$dy/dx=-6/2=-3.$$

Comment: I think I was confused for no reason thinking with the terms "With respect to" overthinking stuff... Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: On this site we use MathJaX to format maths. Pleas read [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) and try to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Sorry! I'll try harder next time :D